# What are the Tits algebras of $\mathrm{SO}(A, \sigma)$ if $A$ is split?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Given a connected linear algebraic group $G$ over a field of characteristic zero, there are several constructions of the so called Tits algebras (see [Sechin and Semenov - *Applications of the Morava K-theory to algebraic groups*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09059), or simply [Rost - *The book of involutions*](https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-44)).

One construction assigns a Tits algebra $A_i$ to any variety $X_i\mathrel{:=} G/P_i$, for $P_i$ a maximal parabolic subgroup of $G$. (Just consider the Dynkin diagram of $G$. Pick one node $i$. It corresponds to $X_i$). The construction is explained in [Merkurjev, Tignol - Multipliers of similitudes and the Brauer group of homogeneous varieties](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1995.461.13).

For example, for $F_4$, all Tits algebras constructed this way are split.

Another construction is to simply pick a representation $\rho: G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$, restrict to the center $Z(G)$, apply the functor $H^2(k, {-})$ and patch this with the long exact Galois cohomology sequence of $1 \rightarrow Z(G) \rightarrow G_{\text{sc}} \rightarrow G \rightarrow 1$, with the second term denoting the universal cover of $G$.  We obtain a map $H^1(k, G) \rightarrow H^2(k, Z(G))$. This is also a construction of Tits algebras. Note that this map depends on the representation chosen in the beginning and thus it becomes clear, how a group can have several Tits algebras. Also it's now clear that the $X_i$ Tits algebras for $F_4$ are trivial: $F_4$ is simply connected and thus each dimension two invariant is trivial.

We consider a non-split central, simple algebra $A$ with orthogonal involution $\sigma$ over $k$ and set $G \mathrel{:=} \mathbf{SO}(A, \sigma)$.

Consider the first involution variety $X_1$. It becomes isomorphic to a quadric over $k(\mathrm{SB}(A))$.

**Question**: Is the Tits algebra of $X_1$ equivalent to $A$ over $k$?  If not, then what is it?

Comment: I tried to add links, but I couldn't find Semenov - Morava K-theory.  Is it [Sechin and Semenov - Applications of the Morava K-theory to algebraic groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09059)?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\H{H}$Also, I changed "its now that the Tits algebras for $F_4$ are trivial" to "it's now *clear* that …"; I hope this was correct.  I am confused how you use the representation $\rho$; the map $\H^1(k, G) \to \H^2(k, Z(G))$ doesn't depend on it.  Do you then compose with $\H^2(k, Z(G)) \to \H^2(k, \GL_n)$ to get $\H^1(k, G) \to \H^2(k, \GL_n)$?  If so, then how do the parameterising cohomology classes in $\H^1(k, G)$ correspond to the nodes $i$ in the Dynkin diagram?

Comment: Yes, this is reference. First one consideres $H^1(k,G) \rightarrow H^2(k,Z(G)$. The image of the respective torsor is the Tits class (I think the Tits class is actually the opposite element). Then you compose with the map (coming from the respresentation) $H^2(k, Z(G)) \rightarrow H^2(k, k^*) $. Note that we restrict $GL_n$ to the center as well, which is $k^*$.

Comment: But a representation $G \to \operatorname{GL}_n$ need not restrict to $\operatorname Z(G) \to \operatorname Z(\operatorname{GL}_n)$ ….

Comment: Well, you need to choose one which "does". I think one actually chooses a character map in Hom$(Z(G), k^*)$.

Comment: Oh, it just notice that is posted on mathoverflow. I intended to make this a mathstackechange post. The answer will be a mere triviality to the experts. But i am not 100% sure about the answer.

Comment: Since it's getting upvotes here, I think you might as well leave it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is $A$.

The key point is that the number 1 indicates the highest weight of the tautological representation $SO(A, \sigma) \subset GL_1(A)$.  The parabolic $P_i$ is the stabilizer of the highest weight line in that representation, and $X_i$ is the orbit of the highest weight line.  (This amounts to the concrete description of $X_1$ as the collection of minimal right ideals in $(A, \sigma)$ that are isotropic.)

References:

1. Book: Knus, Merkurjev, Rost, Tignol “The book of involutions”, AMS, 1998, section 27.B.
2. Paper: Merkurjev, Panin, Wadsworth “Index reduction formulas for twisted flag varieties I”, K-theory vol 10 (1996), pages 575-579.  ([DOI 10.1007/BF00537543](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00537543))

Comment: I was not fully aware of this geometric interpretation.